# Push notification did not received when the application is killed - iOS

Tags: ios, push-notification

Did anyone facing same issue, application did not received notification in development environment when the application had been kill and terminated?

Comment: Please check your SSL certification on server or PEM file.it that correct ?

Comment: Yes, it's correct. If the application running or run in background. It will received the push notification. When I kill or terminated the application. It won't receive the push notification

Comment: Check it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41345889/its-possible-to-change-push-notification-message-before-display-on-device-from

Answer (score 1):

ensure once this you are enabled the Pushnotification and background modes in target -> capablilities

[image]

and this

[image]

Comment: for more information see this https://www.sitepoint.com/developing-push-notifications-for-ios-10/

Comment: Yes, it's correct. If the application running or run in background. It will received the push notification. When I kill or terminated the application. It won't receive the push notification

Answer (score 0):

I think is apple Sandbox problem. Everything is working fine today without any changes.
Thanks all the reply.